# How to provide file/image upload option for customers in their MyAccount area?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, customer-account, image-upload, file-upload

I want to give my customers flexibility that they should attach photos of defected product/items they have received before applying for return/refund!

Presently I am using simple PHP for that.

`<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="picUpload" />
         <input type="submit"/>
</form>`

I use simple `move_uploaded_file()` function to move those images with combined orderID.